# How to limit the editable text in JComboBox?

Tags: java, jcombobox

I already have this in my jcombobox:

```
myjcombobox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!(Character.isDigit(c)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                getToolkit().beep();
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

This code prevents the writing of any character in the jcombobox besides digits. ONLY DIGITS. But since my jcombobox is editable the user can write several digits and that's the problem, i want to set a maximum length of 4 digits but don't know how can i do this....

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add a changelistener, that changes the value to a suitable 4-digit number on change.

Comment: can you give me a little example for that.. i have no idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming your JCombobox is final, you can try this:

```
myjcombobox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                char c = e.getKeyChar();
                if (myjcombobox.getEditor().getItem().toString().length() < 4) {
                    if (!(Character.isDigit(c) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE) || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                        f.getToolkit().beep();
                        e.consume();
                    }
                } else { 
                    e.consume();
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank u soo much, that fix my code perfectly...really apreciated

Comment: Can you get me at least an idea of how you got all that java knowledge? i want a point to start... thanks

Comment: A good point to start is the tutorial by sun. Have a look for JComboBox here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html
For Java in general: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/
And of course practice a lot! ;-) Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Set your own `Document` to the component (assuming it's a `JTextField`):

```
.setModel(new PlainDocument(){

    public void insertString(int offset, String text, AttributeSet attr){
        if(getLength() + text.length() > 4){
            Toolkit.getToolkit.beep();
            return;
        }

        for(char c : text.toCharArray(){
            if(!Character.isDigit(c){
                || (c != KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                || (c != KeyEvent.VK_DELETE)){

                Toolkit.getToolkit.beep();
                return;
            } 

        }
        super.insertString(offset,text,attr);
    }
});
```

Comment: comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent(); will get you the JTextField used in a JComboBox when the JComboBox has setEditable(true).