# JCombobox which accepts only alphabets

Tags: java, swing

How to create a combo box which accepts only alphabets and of length 3?
I have created an auto completion combo box which set editable to true.
Now I want to allow the user to only enter alphabets with length 3 to the input field of a combobox. Any ideas pls?

I added this document filter to textfield of Jcombobox.

```
class AlphaDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

  private final static Pattern CHARACTERS = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z]");

      public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String text,
          AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text != null && CHARACTERS.matcher(text).matches() && (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length()) <= 3){
          fb.insertString(offset, text.toUpperCase(), attr);
        }

      }

      public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text,
          AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
        if (text != null && CHARACTERS.matcher(text).matches() && (fb.getDocument().getLength() + text.length() - length) <= 3){
          fb.replace(offset, length, text.toUpperCase(), attrs);
        }

      }
    }
```

It works if I enter values in combobox. But when I select item it is not getting displayed in combobox because filter dint allow it to.

For eg, if I enter EUR in combobox editor it works. but if I select EUR from the items it doesnt work meaning filter doesnt allow it to display in the editor.

Am I missing something?

Comment: there are slimier question plz search first .for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649587/how-to-limit-the-editable-text-in-jcombobox

Comment: It boils down to configure the editor’s textfield, hence the `JComboBox` is irrelevant.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Search and then provide a code where you're stuck at. Then we can help you, don't ask only for code.

Comment: Don't use a KeyListener (as suggested by the link above).  The suggestion in the above link won't work for pasted text. Swing has newer and betters API's to use.

Answer (score 2):

You need to access the editor of the combo box so you can filter the characters. The default editor of a combo box is a text field. You can access the text field using:

```
ComboBoxEditor editor = comboBox.getEditor();
JTextField textField = (JTextField)editor.getEditorComponent();
```

The best way to filter the characters is to use a `DocumentFilter` on the `Document` of the text field. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Implementing a DocumentFilter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). The tutorial contains a working filter to limit the number of character that can be entered.

You will need to modify the filter to only allow alphabetic characters. Note you will need to modify the `replace()` and `insertString()` methods, since either of those methods might be used to add text to a `Document`.

Edit:

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#editable). There is an example that uses an editable combo box. Note the comment in that section:

*An editable combo box fires an action event when the user chooses an item from the menu and when the user types Enter. Note that the menu remains unchanged when the user enters a value into the combo box. If you want, you can easily write an action listener that adds a new item to the combo box's menu each time the user types in a unique value.*

Comment: Thanks it worked. but can you please help on the issue i faced above.