# Allow textfield to input only number [Java]

Tags: java, jtextfield

I know this has been asked and answered many times but I still can't get the answer that I really need. Hopefully this time, somebody can help me and I thank you in advance. :)

This is what I want in my program, I want user to limit to input only numbers. Whenever they input letters and others there will be a prompt message. I can do that, there is a prompt message for letters and other char but the inputted value still remain, I want it to be cleared.

Please see my code.

```
private void txtQty1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                 
    txtQty1.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {});
    char char_input = evt.getKeyChar();
    if (((char_input < '0') || (char_input > '9')) && (char_input != '\b'))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Number only!","Invalid Input",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        txtQty1.setText(" ");
    }

}
```

Though I clear my textfield, the character that I input still appears.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you! :)

Comment: evt.consume(); should do the trick http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume()

Comment: Use a `DocumentFilter` as demonstrated in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566597/jcombobox-which-accepts-only-alphabets/32572747#32572747. The OP updated the question with a working filter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to create a subclass of DocumentFilter class and use a regular expression to match each inserted string/character if they are digits or not and perform actions accordingly.

Below is a fully working sample code of this working. Thanks to @camickr for pointing out using DocumentFilter is more up-to-date than the old way of extending JTextField to achieve the same result.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.AbstractDocument;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;

public class TestDocumentFilter {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new TestDocumentFilter();
    }

    public TestDocumentFilter() {
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
        ((AbstractDocument) textField.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new CustomDocumentFilter());

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        frame.getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private class CustomDocumentFilter extends DocumentFilter {

        private Pattern regexCheck = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+");

        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offs, String str, AttributeSet a) throws BadLocationException {
            if (str == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (regexCheck.matcher(str).matches()) {
                super.insertString(fb, offs, str, a);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String str, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (str == null) {
                return;
            }

            if (regexCheck.matcher(str).matches()) {
                fb.replace(offset, length, str, attrs);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The newer approach is to use a `DocumentFilter` instead of creating a custom Document. The `DocumentFilter` can be added to any `AbstractDocument`.

Comment: @camickr oh that's new to me, thanks. I will try that. It is true that I used to use the custom jtextfield from a long time ago :)

Comment: For example, see [Implementing a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter). The example filter could be used on a JTextField, JTextArea or JTextPane. No need for different classes to extend different Documents.

Comment: Updated the answer to use DocumentFilter. You know it's very similar to the old way except you just sub-class 1 class instead of subclassing 2 classes.

Comment: Thank you for this @george_h and camickr . I've tried and  really works well even I tried to paste text.

Answer (score 1):

Add line `evt.consume()` in code as below :

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Number only!","Invalid Input",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
 txtQty1.setText(" ");
 evt.consume(); //consume the key type event
```

Detail On http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/InputEvent.html#consume()

---

To disable also paste wrong input in `txtQty1` text field you can use `caretUpdate` event as below :

**Note :** if you use Netbeans GUI form just create caretUpdate event.

```
private void txtQty1CaretUpdate(javax.swing.event.CaretEvent evt) {                                    

    String text = txtQty1.getText();
    if(text != null) {
        if(!text.matches("[0-9]*")) {
            txtQty1.setText(" ");                
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi @developerbhuwan, thank you so much. I've got what I need. :)

Comment: @nhix,  Don't use a KeyListener. That is NOT the way to solve the problem. For example try pasting a string of invalid text into the text field. Your edit will not work.

Comment: @camickr thank you! I've tried it and you're correct. What event should I use?

Comment: @camickr Sorry I overlooked. Thank you! :)

Comment: Agree that it inst good answer, its nevereding hacking. Correct safe and "swingish" way is below (Document or DocumentFilter)